# Does Java duplicate data when calling Collection values() on a Hashtable?

Tags: java, memory-management, hashtable

I want to iterate through the values of a Hashtable, which has a large amount of data (apx. 1 GB). For that, I am using:

```
Hashtable<String,Object> myHashtable = new Hashtable<String,Object>;

// Fill the Hashtable here...

// Get the values as a Collection:
Collection<Object> myValues = myHashtable.values();

// Get the values as an array:
ArrayList<Object> myArray = myValues.toArray();

// Iterate through the values here...
```

So, my question is: Am I multiplying the data stored? Does I have 3 copies of the same values stored in RAM (one copy in the Hashtable, one copye in the Collection, and one copy in the ArrayList)?

If the answer is yes, I copied the data, is there a way to iterate through the values of the Hashtable without duplicating the data?

If the answer is no, then does that mean the Collection stores pointers? In that case, if I modify the data in the Hashtable after having created the Collection, does the Collection reflect that change? (same question for the ArrayList).

Thanks!

Comment: `myValues.toArray()` returns an `Object[]`, not an `ArrayList<Object>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `values()` method does *not* duplicate data, as per the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values%28%29), it returns a view of the values in the map - meaning: if you change the elements in `myValues` then the changes will be reflected on the original map.

On the other hand, `toArray()` *does* duplicate data, (and it returns an **array**, not an `ArrayList` as implied by your code) because it creates a new array with a shallow copy of the elements in `myValues`. Also, because the array holds references to the elements in the original map, if the objects are mutable changes on them will be reflected on the map - but if you modify the array itself (say, setting to null one of its elements) that change won't be reflected on the map.

The simplest way to iterate through the values of a map without creating additional copies of them is to use an iterator on the values:

```
for (Object val : myHashtable.values()) {
    // do something with each value
}
```

And remember, because the values in the map, the contents of `myValues` and the contents of `myArray` are all references to the same objects, any change you make on them will be reflected on the others as well (assuming they're mutable.)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [the Hashtable.values() documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#values%28%29).

> The collection is backed by the map, so changes to the map are reflected in the collection, and vice-versa.

The returned `Collection` contains references to the same objects stored in your `Hashtable`, so data is not "duplicated"; it is merely a *view* of your `Hashtable`.  If you change one of the stored objects, you'll observe the change in both the `Hashtable` and the `Collection` (because it's the same object).